# Where to put custom validator in Laravel?

Tags: laravel-4, custom-validators

[This page](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules) isn't very specific on where one should place the custom validator. You can easily create one:

```
Validator::extend('foo', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return $value == 'foo';
});
```

But where does this go? My gut feel tells me to create a "validators.php" file and include it via global.php. Is that the right place to put it?

Answer (score -2):

You can put your custom validation rule on route.php

Comment: However, like sidneydobber said, you can create your custom class, put it in a subfolder of your app, classmap that folder with composer. Then in your route.php you can simply write
Validator::extends('foo', 'CustomValidator@foo').

If your question is where to put that piece of code, you can put that in your route.php file